# Ember: Log model data in template from a nested route

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js

I have a nested route, that displays an obect of data based on an item that is clicked on.  In Ember, is there a way to log the data in the template for this nested route when I selected an item from the list?

I've only recently started working with Ember, but I have not found where this is asked.  Here is a fiddle where I can display the data using handlebars and calling the objects property nae, but how do I log the whole object to the console in this template?

http://jsfiddle.net/jwevfhzL/

Here is my JS and Templates:

JS:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  fullName: function() {
  return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});

App.User.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'Luke',
    lastName: 'Skywalker'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    firstName: 'Frodo',
    lastName: 'Baggins'
  }
];

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('users', {path: '/'}, function() {
    this.route('show', {path: ':user_id'});
  });
});

App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('user');
  }
});

App.UsersShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
  },
  templateName: 'show'
});
```

Templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{outlet}}
</script>


<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="users">
  <p>List of Users</p>
  <ul>
    {{#each}}
      <li>
        {{#link-to 'users.show' this}}
          {{firstName}}
        {{/link-to}}
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>

  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="show">
  <h3>How do I log the contents of the object in this view?</h3>
  <p>First Name = {{firstName}}</p>
  <p>Last Name = {{lastName}}</p>
  <p>Full Name = {{fullName}}</p>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The right way

The best way to do that will be installing chrome/firefox extension called `ember inspector` for debugging purposes. Once you have the plugin installed you simply go to `Ember -> View Tree`, where you should find row `users.show` with corresponding controller. Click on it and then click `$E` next to the `model` property inside `Own properties` tab. The object will be logged to console.

[image: ember inspector]

See https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector

### The other way

If you would like to log object to console manually you could use `afterModel` or `setupController` on selected route.

```
App.UsersShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
  },
  afterModel: function(model) {
    console.log(model);
  },
  templateName: 'show'
});
```

The `afterModel` is called after resolving promise from your route `model` property. You have guarantee that the ajax request is completed (in case of using restadapter) and you can see your object with the all corresponding data.

Take a notice that you shouldn't put this into `model` instead of `afterModel`. When one click on the link you are passing model directly to route.

```
{{#link-to 'users.show' this}}
```

The `model` is not executed in this case.

Comment: Thank you.  I am working with an API that sends properties which can be anything, so I am going to look into a way to make a loop to output the properties on the current model for the `show` template.  But I was having trouble even figuring out how to access it.